# HoloLens Networking Issues on Windows Holographic Version(21H1)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

Since a while I am working with HoloLens2. My last OS-Versions were 10.0.18362.1005 and 10.0.19041.1109. I am developing with Unity 2019.4.7. My whole code was and still is running great on those old OS-Versions. Now I updated to OS-Version 21H1 and I have huge problems with everything including networking.

For example, my Mixed-Reality-WebRTC Pluging (from Microsoft), which only supports ARM-Architecture, does not work anymore on my new Device. The app crashes after it was successfully starting.

Another thing is, that the DevicePortal does not transmit virtual inputs. Again, on my older HoloLens2´s Virtual Input works great.

Also, even if I disable WebRTC parts of my Project, I still get an Exceptions in my Networking-System which I can´t assign to any cause. In term it is useful for you, I work with windows.Networking Library and in special with DatagramSocket.

I would be really glad if anybody could help me with this. Is OS-Version 21H1 restricted to any specific Unity- or VisualStudio Version (here currently I use 16.4.5)? Or is it Restricted to specific Networking Libraries? Thanks in advance!

Comment: We have checked the release notes of versions after 10.0.19041.1109, it seems like there isn’t any breaking change related to your WebRTC networking and virtual input transmission issue. We always encourage you to try the latest Windows Holographic build, and the current recommendation is to use [Windows Holographic version 21H2  Build 20348.2300](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-release-notes). Could you try upgrading to this build and try again?

Comment: First, thank you for your response. I also went through all release notes and also didn´t find any reason for the behavior. Unfortunately, in my business I can´t upgrade my Device-OS that easy.  I found the reason behind the Networking-Exception and now basic Networking works well but the problem with DevicePortal and WebRTC still exists.  The problem with MR-WebRTC is, if I build with ARM-configuration, the App breaks straight after start. If I build it with ARM64 configuration, the app starts, but throws an exception, but here I guess this results from MR-WebRTC-Incompatibility to ARM64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I was able to fix the Networking Exception. The reason for that is located within my UDP-Communicator which uses DatagramSocket. Since earlier .Net.Sockets was not available at HoloLens2, now it is and I coincidentally came across this information. So I switched my implementation to .Net.Sockets which already exists in my project for editor-usage and now basic networking works fine.

Also, I was able to make WebRTC work again. With one of my Provisioning-Packages I disabled the usage of microphone for mixedReality and it seems like access to those audio-informations is mandatory for MR-WebRTC.

Unfortunately, I still have the same issues with Device Portal.This really looks like a bug.